# Netezza Log of queries and execution time

Tags: netezza

I have been asked to find the log of all of the queries submitted by user name and see the length of time it take for each queries to run.  I understand that there is a web based interface that list this, but we are looking to be able to query it within the Netezza environment.  We don't have to see the actual queries perse just the average run time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `nz_query_history` table contains all the query runtime information including the actual sql command.

```
select *
from dba_monitor.admin.nz_query_history
```

Comment: How can we get the query which characters exceeds more than 64,000